# Liquibase: How to Generate changelog for package/function

Tags: liquibase

Are there any way I can export changelog file for package/function/procedure ? Because sometime I want to use tools for create these objects quickly, I don't want to create them manual by code script or copy.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase by default doesn't support this. You have to create extension or export procedures manually and create changeSets from them.